# c++ subscript operator for 2D matrix between different files

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-keyword, subscript

I had create a template class of 2D matrix.
but subscript operator(LINE 13,14,16~36) canNOT work normally.

If I mark LINE 72~74(dio.cpp), program could be run.
LINE 91~93 CAN work.

If LINE 72~74(dio.cpp) doesNOT mark.
Complie failure and IDE raise an error "call of nonfunction"(BCB5 E2314)

Needs your kindly help!

Thanks

BR

Evyyos

```
001  //[mtrx.h]======================================================================
002  class mtrx
003  {
004     private:
005           unsigned int _row;
006           unsigned int _col;
007           T** _m;
008     public:
009           mtrx();
010           mtrx(unsigned int, unsigned int);
011           ~mtrx();
012  ... ...
013           T& operator()(unsigned int row, unsigned int col);
014           T operator()(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) const;
015  ... ...
016  //c++ subscript operator
017  template<class T> inline T&
018  mtrx<T>::operator () (unsigned int row, unsigned int col)
019  {
020     if((row < this->_row) && (col < this->_col)){
021        return this->_m[row][col];
022     }
023  }
024  
025  //c++ subscript operator
026  template<class T> inline T
027  //mtrx<T>::operator () (int row, int col) const
028  mtrx<T>::operator () (unsigned int row, unsigned int col) const
029  {
030     //if((row < this->_row) && (col < this->_col)){
031     //   return this->_m[row][col];
032     //}
033     if((row < _row) && (col < _col)){
034        return _m[row][col];
035     }
036  }
037  //==============================================================================
038  
039  //[dio.h]======================================================================
040  ... ...
041  #include "..\..\include\mtrx.h"
042  ... ...
043  unsigned long
044     dio_csv_analysis(
045           const char *ifile_name,
046           double smapling_ratio,
047           char fs,
048           unsigned int nn_selected_mask_size,
049           vector <int> inn_input_mask,
050           vector <int> inn_target_mask,
051           mtrx<double> *inn_input_stat,
052           mtrx<double> *inn_target_stat
053  );
054  ... ...
055  //==============================================================================
056  
057  //[dio.cpp]====================================================================
058  ... ...
059  unsigned long
060     dio_csv_analysis(
061           const char *ifile_name,
062           double smapling_ratio,
063           char fs,
064           unsigned int nn_selected_mask_size,
065           vector <int> inn_input_mask,
066           vector <int> inn_target_mask,
067           mtrx<double> *inn_input_stat,
068           mtrx<double> *inn_target_stat
069     )
070  {
071  ... ...
072              inn_input_stat(nn_input_mask_id, NN_INPUT_AVG) = f_item; <<Compile ERR:: all of nonfunction
073              inn_input_stat(nn_input_mask_id, NN_INPUT_MAX) = f_item; <<Compile ERR:: all of nonfunction
074              inn_input_stat(nn_input_mask_id, NN_INPUT_MIN) = f_item; <<Compile ERR:: all of nonfunction
075  
076  ... ...
077  //==============================================================================
078  
079  //[global.h]======================================================================
080  ... ...
081  #include "dio_csv.h"
082  ... ...
083  //==============================================================================
084  
085  //[main.cpp]====================================================================
086  ... ...
087     mtrx<double> nn_input_stat(nn_input_mask_size, 3);
088     mtrx<double> nn_target_stat(nn_target_mask_size, 3);
089  ... ...
090     double m=9,n=5,k=0;
091     nn_input_stat(0,0) = m; <<RUN TIME:: can work normally
092     nn_target_stat(0,0) = n; <<RUN TIME:: can work normally
093     n = nn_target_stat(0,0) - nn_input_stat(0,0); <<RUN TIME:: can work normally
094  ... ...
095  row_count=
096     dio_csv_analysis(
097           dio_csv_file.c_str(),
098           sampling_ratio,
099           ',',
100           nn_selected_mask_size,
101           nn_input_mask,
102           nn_target_mask,
103           &nn_input_stat,
104           &nn_target_stat
105     );
106  ... ...
107  //==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

`mtrx::operator ()` is not the subscript operator, is the function call operator and is invoked like this: `m(x, y)`.

The subscript operator is `mtrx::operator []`. If you need a bidimensional subscript operator you need to have the first subscript return a proxy object that also implements the subscript operator. When the proxy is subscripted, all the parameters need to evaluate the call are ready.

Comment: Proxy objects are not worth the trouble in order to use [x][y] over (x,y).

Comment: @totowtwo: Subscript operator is the 'standard' way to subscribe an array or array-like object. Interfaces are important, specially when working in a generic context.

Comment: The subscript operator has the best *name* for how to index matrices but is rarely used in practice. `boost::ublas::matrix`, `boost::gil::image`, `opencv::Mat` all use `operator(int,int)` rather than proxy objects. I believe `boost::multiarray` focuses on `operator[int]` but that has context of many-dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

`inn_input_stat` is a pointer. use `(*inn_input_stat)(x,y)`. Bare pointers do not define operator(int,int), so the compiler attempts to interpret it as a function.

Comment: Many Thanks!!! (*inn_input_stat)(x,y) CAN WORK. The answer could be understand easly.